# Как cкачать картинку с сайта?

Tags: python

Есть сайт - https://prnt.sc/ptwsi2
Надо сделать скрипт, который заходил на этот сайт и скачивал скриншот.
Всё это надо сделать на питоне.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотеками:

- [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) — для запросов
- [`bs4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) (также [`lxml`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/)) — для парсинга

Алгоритм простой:

1. Получаем `HTML` страницы
2. Находим тег `img` с `id` — `screenshot-image`
3. Получаем ссылку на фото из атрибута `src`
4. Скачиваем и сохраняем фото

***Пример:***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 YaBrowser/19.10.2.195 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}

    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    img_tag = soup.find('img', {'id': 'screenshot-image'})
    photo_url = img_tag['src']

    photo = requests.get(photo_url, headers=headers).content
    return photo


def main():
    url = 'https://prnt.sc/ptwsi2'
    photo = parse(url)

    with open('output.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(photo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А зачем байты (содержимое поля content) преобразовывать в BytesIO, а потом с помощью read сразу преобразовывать обратно, чтобы записать в файл?

Comment: @insolor Действительно, в этом случае это излишне.